# Как высчитать ближайшие дни рождения с помощью LocalDate?

Tags: java, массивы, динамические-массивы

Есть список контактов, каждый контакт содержит день рождения типа LocalDate.
Нужно вывести все контакты, у которых день рождения в ближайшие 2 недели. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Стрим по списку + фильтр + если требуется, сортировка. Вас интересует именно этап сравнения или что?

Comment: да, сейчас уже сделал вариант один. получил день из даты и просто вычел из другой даты полученный день. Но там у меня другие ошибки пошли, не касающиеся вопроса))

Comment: А как с годами обходили ограничение? Имхо, надо добавлять разницу лет м/ду текущим годом и годом рождения и потом уже сравнивать. Но тут есть еще одна тонкость - если текущая дата - конец декабря, а дата рождения - начало января. В этом случае надо добавлять на один год больше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом алгоритм такой:

1. из одной даты вычесть другую. Получим значение в `MILLISECONDS`.
2. Привести значение из `MILLISECONDS` в `{нужную единицу измерения}`.

Здесь подробности: [calculating-days-between-two-dates-with-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165564/calculating-days-between-two-dates-with-java).

Comment: если нет ограничений на версию java то удобнее пользоваться java8 dateTime API о котором автор и спрашивал

Comment: Я привел ссылку на исчерпывающее обсуждение по вопросу. @Виктор, а почему Вы собственно решили, что речь про java8? Возможно автор имел ввиду org.joda.time.LocalDate ?

Comment: прочитал и решил... а почему Вы собственно решили, что речь про joda.time? Возможно автор имел ввиду LocalDate? И почему ответили про Calendar, если прочитали не про него?

Answer (score 0):

Решил добавить свой вариант. Многословный, но более наглядный.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Duration checkedPeriod = Duration.ofDays(14); //За какой период проверяем ДР.

        // Мок-база ДР.
        List<LocalDate> birthDayList = new ArrayList<>();
        birthDayList.add(LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 5));
        birthDayList.add(LocalDate.of(1999, 12, 31));
        birthDayList.add(LocalDate.of(1999, 2, 1));
        birthDayList.add(LocalDate.of(2000, 12, 1));
        birthDayList.add(LocalDate.of(1999, 12, 29));
        // Текущая дата. В реале, естественно, надо использовать .now()
        LocalDateTime current = LocalDateTime.of(
//                LocalDate.now(),
                LocalDate.of(2020, 12, 29),
                LocalTime.MIDNIGHT
        );

        for (var birthDay : birthDayList) {
            // Дата ДР в текущем году.
            LocalDateTime checkingDate = LocalDateTime.of(
                    LocalDate.of(current.getYear(), birthDay.getMonth(), birthDay.getDayOfMonth()),
                    LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
            // Дата ДР в следующем году.
            LocalDateTime checkingDate1 = LocalDateTime.of(
                    LocalDate.of(current.getYear() + 1, birthDay.getMonth(), birthDay.getDayOfMonth()),
                    LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
            // Период до ДР в текущем году.
            Duration duration = Duration.between(current, checkingDate);
            // Период до ДР в следующем году.
            Duration duration1 = Duration.between(current, checkingDate1);
            if (
                    // Если период отрицательный, значит в этом году ДР уже был.
                    // Если положительный, и меньше, чем установленный период для проверки - это нужный нам.
                    !duration.isNegative() && duration.minus(checkedPeriod).isNegative() ||
                    // Период до ДР следующем году отрицательным быть не может.
                    // Если меньше, чем установленный период для проверки - это нужный нам.
                    duration1.minus(checkedPeriod).isNegative()
            )
                System.out.println(birthDay);
        }
    }
```