# Java. Вычисление прошедших лет, месяцев и дней между двумя датами

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

Добрый день. Даны интервалы дат, например: 28.01.2009 - 05.03.2013. Стоит задача высчитать точное количество полных лет, месяцев и дней в этом промежутке. Подскажите как это сделать?

Просто количество дней нахожу так

```
    Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(s1);
    Date endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(s2);

    Calendar calendarStart = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarStart.setTimeInMillis(startDate.getTime());

    Calendar calendarEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarEnd.setTimeInMillis(endDate.getTime());

    long difference = calendarEnd.getTimeInMillis() - calendarStart.getTimeInMillis();
    long days = difference /(24* 60 * 60 * 1000);

    System.out.println(days);
```

Результат надо представить в виде: Лет: 7, Месяцев: 5, Дней: 10

Comment: Получите разность дат в годах. Прибавьте это количество лет к началу, и посчитайте разницу в месяцах. Прибавьте это количество месяцев, и посчитайте разницу в днях. Из полученных разниц сформируйте требуемый результат.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе конкретный пример результата расчетов. Пока непонятно какой хочется получить результат - сразу в годах, месяцах и днях или в зависимости от переданных параметров - только в годах или только в днях.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Всё довольно просто с использованием классов пакета `java.time.*` (в Java 8 и новее):

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("28.01.2009", formatter);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse("05.03.2013", formatter);
Period period = Period.between(startDate, endDate);
System.out.println(period.getYears());      // 4
System.out.println(period.getMonths());     // 1
System.out.println(period.getDays());       // 5
```

Comment: То что надо. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите аналогичные обсуждения по ссылкам.

[Как высчитать ближайшие дни рождения с помощью LocalDate?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/799520/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-localdate)

[Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

[Calculating days between two dates with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165564/calculating-days-between-two-dates-with-java)